# Rundeck: Customize option parameter on job workflow step

Tags: rundeck

I'm using Rundeck-2.6.4 and I'm trying to reuse jobs of common task together with option param to control the variables.

Task B has some option params defined and i've added a workflow step on Task A to link to Task B. However I do not have any way to customize the option parameter in Task A to input to Task B.

Any inputs on this?

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the answer,

http://rundeck.org/1.6.2/manual/job-workflows.html#job-reference-step

Finally, if the Job defines Options, you can specify them in the commandline arguments text field and can include variable expansion to pass any input options for the current job. Format:

-optname  -optname  ...